# JShell possible lossy conversion from double to float

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

I was trying Java9 feature JShell. I'm
not able to set a float value:

```
jshell> float b = 3.5 
Error:
|  incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float
|  float b = 3.5;
jshell> float x =2
x ==> 2.0
```

Comment: try `3.5f` to assign value and search about `lossy conversion from double to float`

Comment: What's the question? Keep in mind that in Java `3.5` is a `double` literal. The equivalent `float` literal is `3.5f`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Java being unduly pernickety.

The *type* of the *literal* `3.5` is a `double`, and you are assigning that to a `float`.

Since the set of possible `float`s is necessarily a subset of the set of possible `double`s, you get a precision lost on conversion warning.

For an easy life, use `3.5f` to denote a `float` literal.

But note that `3.5` can be represented *exactly* in both a `double` and `float`, so on this *specific* occasion, the error is hogwash.

Comment: In the good old days compilers would assume the programmers knew what they were doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the behaviour of Java (as described in the existing answer).  JShell follows Java syntax and semantics exactly -- this is important so you don't develop incorrect code.